# Self Sign certificate on email server

Tags: c#, ssl, smtp

I'm using a test [email server](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) to test out my code in SSL environment.   I used the following command to create a self signed root and a signed certificate.

[image]

[image]

I wrote a simple test program using SmtpClient to send test email and the code is as follow:

```
                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(tFrom.Text, tTo.Text);

                mm.Subject = tSubject.Text;
                mm.Body = tBody.Text;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(tSmtp.Text, Convert.ToInt32(tPort.Text));
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tPass.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tUser.Text))
                {
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tUser.Text, tPass.Text);
                }
                client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(client_SendCompleted);
                client.SendAsync(mm, null);
```

On my server (Smtp4Dev) I have it set to accept TLS connection

[image]

On my client machine I have the following:

[image]

Yet, whenever I send an email I keep getting the error as follow on the server log:

```
 220 Ready to start TLS
 Session ended abnormally.
 System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
```

If I tried this without SSL then I can receive my email fine.  I tried to add the certificate under Personal and Trusted Root Certification but same error still occur.  I am very new to SSL so I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at implementing the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` delegate.  Try something like this before you use `SmtpClient`:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

Returning true and thus accepting all certificates is only a good idea in a dev environment, but you can expand on the delegate implementation to check for other properties and not just blindly return true for everything.